# How to desaturate map with gmap2 plugin?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using jquery gmap2: https://github.com/marioestrada/jQuery-gMap what is based on Google Maps API V3. I'd like to desaturate it, (saturation: -200) but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

I've this code:

```
$('#map1').gMap({

    address: "Sample Address",

    controls: {
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        panControl: false,
        draggable: false,
    },
    zoom: 12,
    markers:[{
            address: "Sample Address",
    }],

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gMap plugin it's self does not seem to handle styling of maps at all, so you need to do it via the actual google.maps.Map instance which refers to your particular map. So, after your code above, place the following:

```
//obtain a reference to the actual google.maps.Map instance
var myGmap = $('#map1').data('gMap.reference');
//create our styles
var styles = [
    {
        stylers:[
            {saturation: -100}
        ]
    }
];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"}
);

myGmap.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
myGmap.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

If you have not already seen this, for more info on styling maps as well as see link at bottom of the following page to googles styled map wizard, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling